Is there an easier way to perform this linear transformation?
I noticed that the following linear transformation problem could be solved by setting up multiple systems of equations:

However, I am interested to know if there is a more concise operation to solve this sort of problem ?.


You have used a too complicated method in this case where all the first coordinates are zero. Indeed, by an almost immediate "inspection", we have :
$$\pmatrix{0\\2\\-1}=-2\pmatrix{0\\-1\\2}-\pmatrix{0\\0\\1}$$
Therefore, applying $T$ on both sides, and using linearity:
$$T\pmatrix{0\\2\\-1}=-2 \ T\pmatrix{0\\-1\\2}-T\pmatrix{0\\0\\1}$$
from which you obtain your result.

Yes, there is.  Here is how you could do it (then try to solve it yourself):

Write $v = (0, 2, -1)$ as a linear combination $v=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3$ of $v_1= (1, 1, 1)$, $v_2=(0, -1, 2)$, and $v_3=(0, 0, 1)$.  (For these particular vectors, it should be relatively easy to find $a_1, a_2, a_3$ without in-depth calculations.)
Now apply linearity of $T$ to compute $T(v) = a_1T(v_1) + a_2T(v_2) + a_3T(v_3)$.

Does that make sense?
P.S.: In the future, please do not include pictures like the one you included.  Instead, use MathJax to typeset (tutorial here).

Oh this makes much sense. I would upvote this answer however apparently I do not have the reputation required to do so.
